# Combining stack profiles

Tags: discussion, migration, asking-questions, user-accounts

Is there a way to manage content from all of the StackOverflow / StackExchange sites (linked by my open id) at once?  Something like a user page that has questions from all five sites ?

Three times my questions have been migrated to StackExchange site and it's annoying having to switch between five different sites to check for answers.

Comment: I bet even this one will be moved to meta.stackoverflow...

Comment: This is not nearly as funny as it looks ... six sites to manage :(

Comment: Did you check the network profile link under the profile picture of your profile page? It isn't that hard.

Comment: More of a list of accounts than questions but better than nothing.

Comment: Many migrations of your questions is a symptom that you haven't taken the time to get to know what these sites are all about.  I encourage you to read the faq for each site, and lurk for awhile, to get a feel for what is considered on-topic and off-topic for the site you are posting the question to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a similar feature was recently added.

1. Go to your profile page
2. Beneath your profile picture ther should be a link called Network Profile. Click that and it will display the summary of all the posts you made across the sites and you can navigate to your questions from there.

Answer (score 1):

Stop posting off-topic questions.  I'm sorry you have to go to different sites to get answers.  Baw.  Oh, look, there's an inbox that tells you who is responding to you on every StackExchange website!

[Derp http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/0.46914000%201302020635.png](http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/0.46914000%201302020635.png)

A river, cry me one.

Comment: Just curious: would that work if he doesn't already have an account on the target site? (although it looks like he does here)

Comment: @Rup: Associated accounts.  Yet another Himalaya to climb.  Woe is thee to be a user here.  Why anybody makes the effort I'll never know.

Comment: Yes, sure - we all have a GUID, so if I have a question migrated from SO to SF then it can look to see if I have an SF account with the same GUID to give question ownership to. What I meant: but what if I don't? Does it store my GUID against the question, or does it create me a disabled user account anyway with the GUID so that it's got a user ID to own the question? And would that work with the supercollider dropdown?

Comment: @Rup: You must associate your accounts.  Oh, the huge manatee.